# NGINX Setting up error_page 503 for different messages (maintenance and heavy load)

Tags: nginx

I currently have an error page set up as follows:

```
error_page 503 @503;

location @503 {
  error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
}
```

This correctly serves the maintenance page when the `/system/maintenance.html` file is present.

I've also created a `/503.html` which contains a message specific to when the site is under heavy load.

What is the best way to serve `error_page 503 /503.html` when the site is receiving too much traffic, but also be able to serve the maintenance page with a 503 status code?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to serve `/system/maintenance.html` if it is present, otherwise `/503.html` ?

Comment: Yes. That'll do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would just be to use `try_files`. That's what it's meant for.

For example:

```
error_page 503 @503;

location @503 {
    try_files /system/maintenance.html /503.html;
}
```